# Как написать sql запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Доброе время суток, есть две таблицы в одной название товара в другой его описание.

Необходимо вывести это дело одним запросом, название у товара есть всегда, а вот описания может и не быть (Мультимагазин)

Как построить это одним SQL SELECT запросом в базу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот хорошая картинка поясняющая все возможные объединения таблиц в одном запросе. Разные диалекты поддерживают разные варианты. Сложные объединения состоят из простых.

[image: SQL JOINS]