# Сколько раз внешний ключ используется в другой таблице?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Предположим, что есть 2 таблицы(просто для примера привожу).  
1 таблица - prof 
2 таблица - per

```
CREATE TABLE  prof (
    id_prof    int(4)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name  varchar(40)
   )

CREATE TABLE  per (
    id_per    int(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name    varchar(40), 
    id_prof int(4) FOREIGN KEY
   )
```

Т.е. есть таблица с профессиями(prof) и с сотрудниками(per), в таблице с сотрудниками есть внешний ключ по которому мы задаем профессию 
Как сделать такой запрос чтобы можно было вывести все данные из таблицы с профессиями(prof) + новый столбец, где напротив каждой записи профессии будет количество сотрудников с данной профессией(т.е сколько раз внешний ключ использовался в таблице per). 
Например, если в таблице 10 сотрудников из них 4 программиста и 6 администраторов, то после запроса выйдет таблица 
1 | программист | 4 
2 | администратор | 6 
Заранее спасибо за ответ!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого существуют групповые функции.

```
select
  prof.id_prof,
  prof.name,
  count(*) cnt    
from prof,
     per
where per.id_prof = prof.id_prof
group by prof.id_prof, prof.name
```

---

Здесь много похожих вопросов-ответов и с примерами и с пояснениями.

Comment: да, все получилось спасибо за ответ. А можно вывести все записи из таблицы prof, т.е. например 10 сотрудников и только у 4 поставлено программист, а админов нет, то вывести программист - 4, администратор - 0

Comment: `LEFT JOIN`, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1112075/365777

Comment: при данном запросе `SELECT prof.id_prof, prof.name, count(prof.id_prof) cnt FROM prof LEFT OUTER JOIN per ON prof.id_prof = per.id_prof GROUP BY 1` выводятся все записи, но там где должно быть количество 0 показывается 1. Не знаете с чем эот может быть связано?

Comment: проблема решена, спасибо за помощь!!! Рабочий запрос: `SELECT prof.id_prof, prof.name, count(id_per) cnt FROM prof LEFT OUTER JOIN per ON prof.id_prof = per.id_prof GROUP BY 1`