# Как задать условия на получение определённых столбцов в результате запроса?

Tags: mysql, sql

Как вернуть результат с определёнными столбцами в зависимости от наличия строк в связанных таблицах?

Если в связанных таблицах нет записей соответствующих условию (таблица `tt` не в счёт), то выводить в результате только строки со столбцами:

```
`vv`.`id`, `vv`.`name`, `tt`.`name_ru`, `vv`.`price`
```

Если есть все записи, то результат должен быть со всеми указанными в `SELECT` столбцами. Перерыл весь интернет, возможно что-то не понял, но из того что я пробовал, ничего не работает. Такая задача вообще выполнима? Если нет, то как иначе можно это реализовать?

Мой запрос (MySQL) частично выполняет эту задумку, но он возвращает все столбцы при любом случае:

```
SELECT `vv`.`id`, `vv`.`name`, `tt`.`name_ru`, `vv`.`price`, /* Столбцы которые необходимо вернуть в любом случае */
`ss`.`data_create`, `ss`.`sell_price`, /* В случае отсутствия результатов в данной таблице, не возвращать данные столбцы */
`tp`.`engine_health`, `tp`.`engine_level`, `tp`.`brake_level`, `tp`.`suspension_level`, `tp`.`transmission_level` /* В случае отсутствия результатов в данной таблице, не возвращать данные столбцы */
FROM `vehicles` `vv`
INNER JOIN `types` `tt`, `statistics` `ss`, `tuning_pack` `tp`
WHERE `vv`.`id` = '1'
AND `vv`.`type_id` = `tt`.`id`
AND `ss`.`vehicle_id` = `vv`.`id`
AND `tp`.`id` = `ss`.`id`
```

Но если `` WHERE `vv`.`id` = '1' `` изменить значение на 2 вместо 1, то под id 2 записей в таблицах `ss` и `tp` нет. Соответственно по задумке, должно вернуть результат со строкой только столбы `vv.id, vv.name, tt.name_ru, vv.price`

Структура таблиц такая:

- vv - Таблица машин - имеет поле которое ссылается на id типа машин
  (из tt)
- tt - Таблица типа машин
- ss - Таблица статистики машин - если есть статистика по машине, то в
  ней есть ссылка на id машины (из vv) и на id состояния машины (из tp)
- tp - Таблица состояния машин

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Количество столбцов в запросе постоянно для всех строк.

Если это возможно для решения вашей задачи, то в одном столбце можно выводить разную информацию из разных столбцов по условию. Для этого можно, например, воспользоваться функциями `coalesce` или `case`.

Так `coalesce` принимает список значений и возвращает первое из них, которое не равно `NULL`. Т.е. если бы в таблице `tt` была дата, то `coalesce(ss.data_create, tt.data_create)` вернул ту дату, которая первая не пустая.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробовал эти варианты. Правда подходят мне частично, так как они помогают мне регулировать значения в столбцах которые в любом случае выведутся, даже если их нет в базе, как раз благодаря таким конструкциям. Но, я немного по экперементировав с данными конструкциями, выяснил что проблема в самом условии. Если хотя бы одно условие не верно, то не выводится ни одна запись. По этому, моя задумка получаетя не реализуема при таких условиях в WHERE и сейчас я думаю как должно выглядеть условие, что бы задумка всё же реализовалась. Уже согласен даже на подзапросы или 2 запроса в подряд.

Comment: Но пока что не знаю как это реализовать, потому что таблицы связанные и немного не получается.

Comment: Думаю, надо смотреть в сторону `LEFT JOIN`. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1112075/365777

Comment: Благодарю! В общем запрос у меня получился но опять частично, который выводит все столбцы, но всё правильно. Если нет соответствий в других таблицах, то в этих столбцах null, ещё бы от них избавиться и было бы прекрасно.